# How to check ETag before Request in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I want to request a URL every minute. But before I request the whole page, I want to check if it is updated based on ETag/Content-length/Age in the header. How can I implement this in Scrapy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [scrapy downloader middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) it comes with an implementation of [RFC2616 policy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#rfc2616-policy)

> - Do not attempt to store responses/requests with no-store
>     cache-control directive set
> - Do not serve responses from cache if no-cache cache-control directive is set even for fresh responses
> - Compute freshness lifetime from max-age cache-control directive
> - Compute freshness lifetime from Expires response header
> - Compute freshness lifetime from Last-Modified response header (heuristic used by Firefox)
> - Compute current age from Age response header
> - Compute current age from Date header
> - Revalidate stale responses based on Last-Modified response header
> - Revalidate stale responses based on ETag response header
> - Set Date header for any received response missing it